# Find pair in array with maximum sum using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Not sure the best way to solve this using recursion. Below is what I have tried so far:

```java
public static void findSum(int[] a, int sum, int i, int j) {

    if (i == a.length)
        return;
    if (j == a.length)
        return;

    sum = (a[i] + a[j] > sum) ? (a[i] + a[j]) : sum;
    System.out.println("Sum:" + sum + ", i:" + i + ",j:" + j);

    findSum(a, sum, i, j + 1);
    i++;
    j = i;
    findSum(a, sum, i, j + 1);

    return;
}
```

**Given input** : `int[] a = {5, 4, 7, 3, 9, 2}`
**Expected output** : 7+9 -> `16`

Plus I am getting many number of iterations which must be reduced.

Comment: are you required to use recursion?

Comment: @Heslacher 16 is alright, just the 5 should be 7

Comment: @slepic you are correct.

Comment: why not just find the two largest numbers in the array? sort the array descending, it's the first two elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the answer is the sum of the two greatest elements in the array. You only need one pass to find both of them.

The idea is that you go from through the array and keep track of top 2 elements in the array. The code will be simplier if the function requires to be called on a valid input data (an array of length >= 2) and first two elements already compared. The function then takes the next element of the array, updates the top 2 pair and moves onto the next element.

I assume you have to use recursion, but the code could be easily rewritten using a loop.

```
public static void findSum(int[] a, int greatest, int secondGreatest, int currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == a.length) {
        System.out.println("Sum:" + (a[greatest] + a[secondGreatest]) + ", i:"+greatest+",j:"+secondGreatest);
        return;
    }
    if (a[currentIndex] > a[greatest]) {
        // found the new top; the current top becomes the second
        secondGreatest = greatest;
        greatest = currentIndex;
    } else if (a[currentIndex] > a[secondGreatest]) {
        // found the new second-greatest, but so the current top stays the same
        secondGreatest = currentIndex;
    }
    findSum(a, greatest, secondGreatest, currentIndex + 1);
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
if (a.length >= 2) {
    // Rank the first two elements in the array and initiate the recursion
    int greatest = a[0] > a[1] ? 0 : 1;
    int secondGreatest = greatest == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    findSum(a, greatest, secondGreatest, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. I think I went to a wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void findSum(int[] a, int sum, int i, int j) {
```

`a` is not a good name, neither is `i` and `j`.

Neither is `findSum`, as I would expect it to find and return an `int`. `printSum` would be a better choice.

---

You don't need a `return` at the end of the function.

---

```java
if(i == a.length)
    return;
if(j==a.length)
    return;
```

---

This is not very fault tolerant, you should check whether the given values exceed the length of the arrays. That way you will also catch faulty input.

---

```java
sum = (a[i] + a[j] > sum) ? (a[i] + a[j]) : sum;
```

I'm not a fan of ternary operator constructs, and with these variable names the code ends up extremely hard to read.

---

There are a few possible solutions to this, another is to use two nested loops.

```java
int sum = -1;

for (int firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < numbers.length; firstIndex++) {
    int firstValue = numbers[firstIndex];
    
    for (int secondIndex = 0; secondIndex < numbers.length; secondIndex++) {
        if (firstIndex != secondIndex) {
            int secondValue = numbers[secondIndex];
            int newSum = firstValue + secondValue;
            
            if (newSum > sum) {
                sum = newSum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The number of iterations over the array is n^n, though, we are iterating over the array once of every of its items. Looking for the two biggest values in a single run (without any recursion) and returning the sum of these is for sure the most efficient one.